# Symfony 2 create query

Tags: php, symfony-2, symfony

```php
createQuery("select p.name from blogBundle:Person p
         where p.id not in(select c.person from blogBundle:Category c)")->execute();
```

E estou recebendo este erro:

```
Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression
```

Answer (score 0):

Troque sua DQL por:

```
SELECT p
FROM blogBundle:Person p
WHERE p.id NOT IN(
    SELECT IDENTITY(p.id)
    FROM blogBundle:Category c
    JOIN c.person p)
```

Note o `IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é o `->execute()`. Para rodar a Query você precisa utilizar o `getResult()`.

A forma correta é:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("select p.name from blogBundle:Person p
         where p.id not in(select c.person from blogBundle:Category c)")->getResult();
```